# IE9 @media query issue with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

I'm using jQuery to load content into a (display:none;) div. When I display the div, IE9 is applying the wrong @media queries, which then snap back correctly if I resize the browser.

```
@media (min-width: 1080) { }
@media (max-height: 500px) { }
```

In this case it's not applying the first media query, but it is applying the second. With my browser maximized, it should be the other way around.

```
@media (min-width: 1080) { }
@media (min-height: 1px) and (max-height: 500px) { }
```

In this case it's not applying either media query when maximized. When my browser height is minimized, it still won't fire either one, even though the second should then fire.

Lets just say @media queries aren't applied right to dynamically loaded content. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. I've found the solution and it was respond.js. Without it, all media queries worked well in IE9. But i needed it for IE8 so i updated to the lasted version but nothing changed. Then i used version 1.3.0 from one of my "good working" projects and that did the trick.